# Jest - Challenge4 mock function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

Consider the function closingTask(task_name),

```
function closingTask(task_name){
var success_flag=false;
  for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      if(tasks[i].task_name === task_name) {
         tasks[i].status="closed";
         success_flag=true;
       }
  }
return success_flag;
}
```

Write a test for the above function, which mocks the real implementation of returning success flag to returning the closed task itself.

Comment: Where does `tasks` defined?

Comment: in frescoplay..

Comment: test('First Mock Function', () => {
  mockedFun =  jest.fn();
  mockedFun.mockImplementation(function (task_name) {
    var success_flag=false;
      for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      if(tasks[i].task_name === task_name) {
         tasks[i].status="closed";
         success_flag=true;
       }
  }
});
console.log(mockedFun('task_name'));
expect(mockedFun('task_name')).toBe(true);
});

Comment: this code i have been tried...

Comment: we asuming tasks as array

Comment: Stop posting private organization property over public domains.

Answer (score 0):

```
test("test mock fn", ()=>{
    const mockFn = jest.fn();
    mockFn.mockImplementation(function(task_name){

           mockFn.genMockFn(expect(success_flag).toBe(true))
     expect(status).toBe('closed')
   })

})
```

Comment: Please explain your snippet of code. Don't just paste code  out-of-the-blue without explaining how it works and solves the OP's issue.